# Node.JS + Express show loading page while getting real page content

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Basically, I have a system which goes to a Database, fetches some information, then goes to some other sites, and fetches some information. This takes about 3 seconds. What I'd like to do, is display a `This Page Is Loading` page while the server is fetching the rest of the data, and once all the data is fetched, I'd like the server to send the destination page.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', '/app/public/')
app.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    //Need to send `This Page Is Loading` here.
    //Contact DB (takes 3 seconds)
    res.send("home/index")//Send the final page.
})
```

I am using Node.JS + Express + Ejs, so we might be able to pull the DB info in the ejs file and display loading screen. Not too sure thou..

An idea that I've got.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', '/app/public/')
function getdbinfo(name){
    //getinfo
    return info
}
app.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    res.send("home/index",{req,getdbinfo})//Send a page with get info function.
})
```

And on the ejs page, we would need to display a loading page and in the background make the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found that the best way to do this is by sending a loading page which does the actual request and awaits for that to process.
Here's the source I used
[How to dynamically render/load pages in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573540/how-to-dynamically-render-load-pages-in-express)

Comment: the link does not answer this question. It doesnt make use of express, rather use client side AJAX

Comment: The intention was that you would send a dedicated loading page with indeed in this case an AJAX request scripted into it which would request and await the actual page. However nowadays I would rather make use of sockets or something alike for problems like these. Besides this and at the time I wasn't aware that IPC exists either.